# Leaflet Realtime - previous markers remain on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I work with the leaflet plugin **leaflet-realtime** by Per Liedman.

https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime

In my application, the user can switch between different realtime JSON sources. My problem is, if I change the source, the previous markers remain on the map.

I made a plunk with a modified earthquake example, here you can see the behavior.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/MzecRNp0ocAuCQF6?preview

Maybe something with `remove`, but I don't know where and how to use it.

Working with a LayerGroup and clearLayers() before reading the new data works, but it is not nice ("blinking markers").

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to keep track of the layers you add, and remove them as needed, right now you never remove any, only add new ones.

Comment: @JDunken, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. `leaflet.realtime` provides the function `setUrl()` (not in the README but mentioned here https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/issues/15)

Changed the script.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/weeikt129ADzHFrh?preview

**Important:** "`leaflet.realtime` version 2 and up of this plugin is _only compatible with Leaflet 1.0 and later. Use earlier versions of Leaflet Realtime if you need Leaflet 0.7 compatibility." See README.md